# How does one evalue an array of boolean values in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm constructing an array of boolean values through a loop (doesn't have to be `true` | `false`, I can choose any values to append to the array, eg `1` | `0`).

This leaves me with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

bool_arr=(true true true)
```

What I need at this stage, is an if-else that lets me check whether all the values in the array are `true`:

```
if [ ??? ]; then
  echo "all true"
else
  echo "not all true"
fi
```

Can someone propose a replacement for `???` in the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `true` and `false`, something like:

```
if [[ ! ${bool_arr[*]} =~ false ]]; then
  echo "all true"
else
  echo "not all all true"
fi
```

Basically, use a regular expression to look for a false element in the expanded-out array.

Comment: Just for completeness: A regexp, as you suggested, is certainly possible, but wildcard matching would do equally well in this case: `if [[ ! ${bool_arr[*]} == *false* ]]; then`